# Unable to get right file path through StreamReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, streamreader

In my `MVC` application I am trying to open a file for reading through StreamReader, the path the I’ve given to it is this, keeping the relative position of file from bin folder:

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Content/files/text/email.txt");
```

But when I’m running it am getting this error over it:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Content\files\text\email.txt.

This is very confusing as I don’t know to how to stop it to stop reading the path from the root directory but read it from application root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this, if you're talking about winforms application.

```
var tr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Content\files\text\email.txt"));
```

UPDATE: 
You don't need StreamReader for a web application. It's very simple:

```
string text = new WebClient().DownloadString("URL_TO_WHEREEVER");
```

Comment: can you please tell what directory whould in Include inorder to use `Application.StartupPath` .. I'm trying to use `using System.Windows.Forms` but its being not found and given an error?

Comment: What's the error? Class `Application` is a part of *`System.Windows.Forms` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Comment: when I'm `using System.Windows.Forms` its showing `.Windows` in red as its being not found.

Comment: Is this a winforms application or something else?

Comment: Rewrite your question, please. You shoud make it obvious. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thankyou, U r rite I shld mentioned it in my question, However i put the tag of `mvc` which was removed by editor.

Comment: I'm using ur way `string text = new WebClient().DownloadString("Content/templates/text.txt");` and I'm still getting this error.
`Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\......`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.StartupPath` or `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`

like

```
TextReader tr = 
     new StreamReader(
         Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                      "Content", "files", "text", "email.txt")
         );
```

Comment: @usr, +1 to both you you Love Path.Combine!

Comment: The problem presists even after using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`